# Can I use regex to replace two or more colons with two colons only

Tags: c#, regex

The developer has coded this but it seems like a not so clean implementation also it does not work if the user enters many colons. I would like to use regex but is it possible for regex to check for two or more colons and replace with just two?

```
renameString = renameString.Replace(":::::::", "::");
renameString = renameString.Replace("::::::", "::");
renameString = renameString.Replace(":::::", "::");
renameString = renameString.Replace("::::", "::");
renameString = renameString.Replace(":::", "::");
```

Does anyone have any suggestions on a better way that this can be done?

For reference here's the full code for that method:

```
if (renameString.StartsWith(":") || renameString.EndsWith(":"))
{
    AcceptText.IsEnabled = false;
    IsValidDeckName = false;
}
else
if (renameString.Contains("::"))
{
    renameString = renameString.Replace(":::::::", "::");
    renameString = renameString.Replace("::::::", "::");
    renameString = renameString.Replace(":::::", "::");
    renameString = renameString.Replace("::::", "::");
    renameString = renameString.Replace(":::", "::");
    IsValidDeckName = true;
    AcceptText.IsEnabled = true;
}
else
{
    IsValidDeckName = true;
    AcceptText.IsEnabled = true;

}
```

Any suggestions on if this can be improved would be appreciated.

Comment: What should happen if the string contains a sequence of more than seven colons in a row - should the additional colons remain? e.g. if the original string were "::::::::" should the result be ":::"?

Comment: Any more than two colons should just be converted to two colons.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Use Regex `Regex.Replace(renameString,"::+","::")`

Answer (score 5):

Use regular expressions:

```
renameString = Regex.Replace(renameString, @":{3,}", "::");
```

In words: replace all sequences of at least 3 occurrences of the character ':' by "::".